# How to use AJAX in IE

Tags: php, javascript, ajax, internet-explorer

i'm using IE and I need to do a simple AJAX that will display a table with values from the database once a dropdown has been changed.

Here is my script:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
 function getXML()
{
var req;
try {
    req = new XMLHttpRequest();
} catch (trymicrosoft) {
    try {
      req = new ActiveXObject("Msxml2.XMLHTTP");
    } catch (othermicrosoft) {
      try {
        req = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
      } catch (failed) {
        req = null;
      }
    }
}

if (!req){

  return null;
} else {
   return req;
}
}
 function filter(month, year)
 {


if(getXML()){
 var xmlhttp = getXML();
 xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
{
   if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
 {
 document.getElementById("mandayTable").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;
  }

}
 xmlhttp.open("GET","ajax/filterMandays.php?m="+month+"&y="+year,true);
xmlhttp.send();
} else {
alert("Error initializing XMLHttpRequest!");
}
}

</script>
```

and here is my ajax php

```
<?php

        $q = "SELECT md.mandays_id,md.employeenum,md.month,md.year,md.required_man_days,d.firstname,d.lastname 
        FROM tbl_mandays md,tbl_employee_details d 
        WHERE md.active = '1' 
        AND md.employeenum = d.employeenum 
        AND md.month = '10';"; //employee_details WHERE approver = 0"



        $res = $db->Execute($q);

        echo "<table border = 1>";

        echo "<tr><th>Employee Number</th><th>First Name</th><th>Last Name</th><th>Month-Year</th><th>Required Man Days</th><th>Edit/Delete</th></tr>";

    /while($rows = $res->FetchRow()) 
        for($i=0;$i<5;$i++)
        {
                                                    $mandays_id = $rows[0];

                        $empnum = $rows[1];

                        $month_year = $rows[2] ."-" .$rows[3];

                        $required_man_days = $rows[4];

                        $firstname = $rows[5];

                        $lastname = $rows[6];

                                                    echo "<tr><td>".$empnum  . "</td><td>".$firstname ."</td><td>".$lastname ."</td><td>" . $month_year ."</td><td>" .$required_man_days  . "</td><td width = \"200\" align = \"center\"><a href = 'edit_mandays.php?mandays_id=$mandays_id');'>Edit/Delete</a></td></tr>";
        }



        echo "</table>";

        ?>
```

THe problem is that on the first "ONCHANGE" it does not do anything.
on the 2nd "ONCHANGE" the headers of the table in the php code is the only one that's being echoed.

I alsoi tried doing it without the query and changing the loop into for($i=0;$i<5;$i++) and changed the qvalues to be displayed into "1" but still it does noty go into the loo[ and display it.

what seems to be the problem? :(

Comment: "it doesn't seem to do what it does. what seems to be the problem? " You have not seemed to tell us what the problem is. Your description of the actual problem is missing.

Comment: @epascarello , THe problem is that on the first "ONCHANGE" it does not do anything.
on the 2nd "ONCHANGE" the headers of the table in the php code is the only one that's being echoed.

I alsoi tried doing it without the query and changing the loop into for($i=0;$i<5;$i++) and changed the qvalues to be displayed into "1" but still it does noty go into the loo[ and display it.

Comment: You should look into jquery - it makes it consistent across browsers and pretty simple ...

Comment: ONCHANGE of what? Have you looked to see if the correct data is being sent out [Fiddler](http://www.fiddler2.com/fiddler2/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Download and use jQuery for your website: http://docs.jquery.com/Downloading_jQuery#Download_jQuery

And then your code will be something like this:

```
$('.mydropdown').change(function(){
  //get values for month, year
  $.ajax({
    url: "ajax/filterMandays.php?m="+month+"&y="+year,
    type: "GET",
    success: function(data){
      //data is returned back
      $('#mandayTable').html(data);
    }
  });

});
```

Comment: This is a good suggestion (jQuery is a hell of a lot cleaner and abstracts away at lot of the inconsistencies between browsers) but doesn't necessarily help the issue at hand. In addition to cleaning up the code with jQuery, I'd say fire up Fiddler (or something similar) to see what is actually happening with the call.

Answer (score 3):

Start here : https://developer.mozilla.org/en/AJAX/Getting_Started , Mozilla explains the correct way to do this across browsers. Later, you may consider jQuery for cross-browser compatibility once you've learned the basics